# How can I restart synchronous reading from webcamera every time it fails?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I am trying to read from a web camera in synchronous mode using Microsoft Media Foundation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <mfidl.h> 
#include <Mfapi.h> 
#include <Mfreadwrite.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Mfplat.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Mf.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Mfreadwrite.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"mfuuid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"shlwapi.lib")
int main()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    DWORD dwCoInit = COINIT_MULTITHREADED;
    hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, dwCoInit);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return -1;
    hr = MFStartup(MF_VERSION);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return -2;

    CComBSTR name("M034-WDR");
    
    CComPtr<IMFMediaSource> pMediaSource;
    CComPtr<IMFSourceReader> pSourceReader;
    CComPtr<IMFMediaType> pMediaType;
    
    
    // Find all camera sources:
    CComPtr<IMFAttributes> pAttributes;
    MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 1);
    pAttributes->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE, MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID); // camera source
    CComHeapPtr<IMFActivate*> ppActivates;
    UINT32 nActivateCount = 0;
    MFEnumDeviceSources(pAttributes, &ppActivates, &nActivateCount);

    // Loop over the camera sources, find the one with correct name:
    CComPtr<IMFActivate> pActivate;
    for (UINT32 nIndex = 0; nIndex < nActivateCount; nIndex++) {
        CComHeapPtr<WCHAR> name_i;
        UINT32 length;
        ppActivates[nIndex]->GetAllocatedString(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_FRIENDLY_NAME, &name_i, &length);
        if (wcscmp(name_i, name) == 0) {
            pActivate = ppActivates[nIndex];
        }
        reinterpret_cast<CComPtr<IMFActivate>&>(ppActivates[nIndex]).Release();
    }
    if (!pActivate) { // camera with name not found
        return -3;
    }
    IMFMediaSource* source;
    hr = pActivate->ActivateObject(__uuidof(IMFMediaSource), (VOID**)&source);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return -4;
    pMediaSource = source;

    hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(pMediaSource, NULL, &pSourceReader);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return -5;

    IMFMediaType* mediaType;
    hr = pSourceReader->GetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, &mediaType);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return -6;

    unsigned int width, height;
    hr = MFGetAttributeSize(mediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, &width, &height);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return -7;

   
    while (true) {
        CComPtr<IMFSample> pSample;
        DWORD dwControlFlags = 0;
        DWORD* pdwActualStreamIndex = NULL;
        DWORD pdwStreamFlags;
        LONGLONG timestamp;

        OutputDebugStringA("MF:Before ReadSample()");
        hr = pSourceReader->ReadSample(0,//dwStreamIndex,
            dwControlFlags,
            pdwActualStreamIndex,
            &pdwStreamFlags,
            &timestamp,
            &pSample);
        OutputDebugStringA("MF:After ReadSample()");
        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << "MF:ReadSample() failed. hr = " << std::hex << hr << ".";
            OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());
        }
        if (pSample == NULL) {
            OutputDebugStringA("MF:ReadSample(): got null sample.");
        }

    }
}
```

The code above works fine on my laptop with one such webcam.
On another PC with another such webcam however; it runs fine for ca 1 minute before it starts to fail:

```
00000920    54.00323105 [7008] MF:Before ReadSample()   
00000921    54.00324631 [7008] MF:After ReadSample()    
00000922    54.00325012 [7008] MF:ReadSample() failed. hr = c00d3ea2.   
00000923    54.00326538 [7008] MF:ReadSample(): got null sample.
```

Looking up the error code:

```
C:\temp>Err_6.4.5.exe c00d3ea2
# for hex 0xc00d3ea2 / decimal -1072873822
  MF_E_VIDEO_RECORDING_DEVICE_INVALIDATED                        mferror.h
# The video recording device is no longer present.%0
```

Anyways the Microsoft Camera application also experiences problems. Every minute ca. the image goes black for 1 sec ca. before the camera appears to be restarted.

How can I restart my code like Microsoft Camera does?